# How to perform multiple inserts In knex transaction with dependent validity checks between inserts?

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I'm writing a multi-step knex transaction that needs to insert multiple records into a table. Each of these records needs to pass a validity check written in Node before it is inserted.

I would batch perform the validity checks then insert all at once except that two records might invalidate each other. I.e. if I insert record 1, record 2 might no longer be valid.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to query the database in a transaction-aware fashion. During the the validity-check of the second record, my queries (used for the validity checks) do not show that the first insert exists.

---

I'm using the `trx` (transaction) connection object rather than the base `knex` object. I expected this would fix it since the transaction connection object is supposed to be promise aware, but alas it did not.

```
await knex.transaction(async trx => {

        /* perform validity checks and insert if valid */

        /* Check the record slated to be created 
         * against the rules to ensure validity. */

        relationshipValidityChecks = await Promise.all(
          relationshipsToCreate.map(async r => {
            const obj = {
              fromId: r.fromId,
              toId: r.toId,
              type: r.type,
              ...(await relationshipIsValid( // returns an object with validity boolean
                    r.fromId, 
                    r.toId, 
                    r.type, 
                    trx // i can specify which connection obj to use (trx/knx)
               ))
            };
            if (obj.valid) {
              await trx.raw(
                `
                insert into t1.relationship
                (from_id, to_id, type) values
                (?, ?, ?)
                returning relationship_key;
                `,
                [r.fromId, r.toId, r.type]
              );
            }

            return obj;
          })
        );
}
```

When I feed in two records that are valid by themselves but invalidate each other, the first record should be inserted and the second record should return an invalid error. The `relationshipIsValid` is somewhat complicated so I left it out, but I'm certain it works as expected because if I feed the aforementioned two records in separately (i.e. in two different endpoint calls) the second will return the invalid error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi all. I was able to accomplish what I wanted by using the bluebird package's `Promise.mapSeries` to get the inserts to take place in the correct order. I also found I had an issue with a timestamp check in my validator because the transaction "freezes time" and thus a `<= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` was needed instead of the `< CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` that i previously had.

Comment: There is no reason why to use Promise.all / map series in this case... you could just do simple `for` -loop and `await` each query inside the loop separately.